# Searching in specific fields of types

Tags: elasticsearch

Consider the following query:

```
{
    "query" : {
        "match_phrase" : {
            "_all" : "Smith"
        }
    }
}
```

How would I specify in which fields of which types it may search, instead of searching in everything? (field names may be non-unique across types)

I've tried the query below, but it didn't work (it doesn't return results, it does when I remove `person.` from all fields):

```
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "Smith",
      "fields": [
        "person.first_name",
        "person.last_name",
        "person.age"
      ],
      "lenient": true
    }
  }
}
```

I'm sending these queries to `http://localhost:9200/tsf-model/_search`.

Comment: Can you also share your mapping? As well as the URL you're sending your search query to?

Comment: @Val I'm not using any explicit mapping. I've added the URL I'm sending my queries to.

Comment: You should explain which fields of what type you're like to query

Comment: @Val The fields and types involved in the query are dynamic and based off of the users authorisation. The query needs to work for all datatypes, hence I've added "lenient". The problem I'm running into is that I can't define in which fields in which types the query should take place. I can define fields, but they'll apply to all types that have the same field name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can build your query dynamically, I think you can use a combination of your `multi_match` query and a [`type` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-type-query.html) for each type, in order to achieve what you want:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "minimum_should_match": 1,
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "filter": [
              {
                "type": {
                  "value": "type1"
                }
              },
              {
                "multi_match": {
                  "query": "Smith",
                  "fields": [
                    "field1",
                    "field3",
                    "field5"
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "filter": [
              {
                "type": {
                  "value": "type2"
                }
              },
              {
                "multi_match": {
                  "query": "Smith",
                  "fields": [
                    "field2",
                    "field4",
                    "field6"
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, works as expected! I'm curious how it'll perform with more types, field and a lot of data, but that's a question for later I suppose :)

Comment: I just realized that `score` is 0 for all returned results, is there a way to keep relevancy scores for the returned results?

Comment: Yes, you can replace `filter` by `must`and that will do the trick.